# Entanglement distillation using separability criterion

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

It has been shown that a state $\varrho$ of a $2 \times 2$ system is separable if, and only if, its partial transposition $\varrho^{T_{2}}$ is a non-negative operator, i.e., if all eigenvalues $\varrho^{T_{2}}$ are nonnegative. Here the partial transposition $\varrho^{T_{2}}$ associated with the arbitrary product orthonormal $f_{i} \otimes f_{j}$ basis is defined by the matrix elements in this basis:
$$
\varrho_{m \mu, n \nu}^{T_{2}} \equiv\left\langle f_{m} \otimes f_{\mu}\left|\varrho^{T_{2}}\right| f_{n} \otimes f_{\nu}\right\rangle=\varrho_{m \nu, n \mu}
$$
Clearly the matrix $\varrho^{T_{2}}$ depends on the basis, but its eigenvalues do not. Hence one can check separability using an arbitrary product orthonormal basis in Hilbert space $C^{2} \otimes C^{2}$
Suppose now that $\varrho$ is inseparable, and let $\psi$ be an eigenvector associated with some negative eigenvalue of $\varrho^{T_{2}}$. Since in the process of distillation Alice and Bob can perform local unitary transformations, we can assume without loss of generality that $\psi$ is of the form
$$
\psi=a e_{1} \otimes e_{1}+b e_{2} \otimes e_{2}
$$
where $\left\{e_{i}\right\}$ form the standard basis in $C^{2}$ and $a, b \geq 0$. Now $\left\langle\psi\left|\varrho^{T_{2}}\right| \psi\right\rangle<0$ implies
$$
\left\langle I \otimes W \psi_{2}\left|\varrho^{T_{2}}\right| I \otimes W \psi_{2}\right\rangle<0 
\tag5$$
where $\psi_{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(e_{1} \otimes e_{1}+e_{2} \otimes e_{2}\right)$ and
$$
W=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
a & 0 \\
0 & b
\end{array}\right]
$$
Let us denote by $\tilde{\varrho}$ the state emerging after performing the operation given by $I \otimes W$,
$$
\tilde{\varrho}=\frac{I \otimes W \varrho I \otimes W}{\operatorname{Tr} I \otimes W \varrho I \otimes W}
$$
This state describes the subensemble of the pairs of particles, which passed the local filter described by the operator $W$. Now the inequality (5) implies
$$
\operatorname{Tr} P_{2}^{T_{2}} \tilde{\varrho}<0 \tag8
$$

Can anyone explain how to show (8) using (5)?

Comment: What is $P_2$ ? And would the answer be clear if the transpose were on the $\tilde\rho$ instead?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch $P_2$ is given by $|\psi_{2}\rangle\langle\psi_{2}|$ yes, that would help